# Firebase Cloud Messaging tokens stop working - 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have a problem where Firebase Cloud Messaging tokens seem to have stopped working.  We register with Firebase when the application first starts-up and then we call an API to store the token on our server.

We upgraded the app last night and checked that a sample of devices successfully registered themselves and that we could send messages.

Today, however, some calls to Firebase from our server are returning:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

These calls are using the same tokens as last night.  Half are working and half not.

We don't have any code that explicitly unregisters our app.  What else might have caused this issue?

The app is written in C#/Xamarin and we're using [CrossGeek's plugin for Firebase](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin).

Thanks,

J.

Comment: Sounds like you've got some tokens which are no longer valid. I think you get 404 when a token is invalid. Are you able to identify specific tokens which are returning 404 when you try to send messages to them? You might be able to see a pattern.

Comment: Current thinking is that Google invalidated the tokens for some reason and we missed the callback.  Not sure why Google might have invalidated them - we took no action that would have triggered it.  We can't see a difference between the ones that continued to work and the others.